# nginx - map domains to docroot

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, domains

I have several domain names and several document root, like that :

```
toto.exemple.com /var/www/exempleOne
titi.exemple.com /var/www/exempleTwo
[...]
```

Basically what I want to do, is using only one server block / vhost file for all the domains.

I tried to used nginx map for this, and did the following :

```
map $host $docroot{
  toto.exemple.com /var/www/exempleOne;
  titi.exemple.com /var/www/exempleTwo;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
        location / {
          root   $docroot;
          expires           30d;
        }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, it seems like nginx is using the default document root (/etc/nginx/html/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `$http_host` as the variable instead of `$host` in the `map`.

Then, you could also use a `default` item in the `map`, setting it to some default value.

This way one can see if nginx evaluates the map at all for the `root` statement. If nginx tries to fetch data from the `default` directory, then it means that something is wrong with the variable `map` is using.

If it still fetches from the nginx default `root` directory, then it means that nginx does not correctly evaluate the `map` here.

I would also recommend setting the `root` outside the `location /` block.